# The websocket is giving error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sockets

Greetins.

I am writing a browser plugin for a webpage which runs over HTTPS. My socket-server is in PHP, so creating a websocket on javascript. But the websocket is giving following error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://URL:8300/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I overlooked differents forums and didn't find decision of this issue that suit me. I tried to add ProxyPass rule and it result as 503 error Throw http:// protocol all work correctly, server is running, but on https:// error persist. Socket-server started on server and I coul loged in with telnet, handshake is confirmed and I see log of messages.

```
Server example download from here - https://www.sanwebe.com/downloads/50-websocket-example
```

Can someone tell how to remove this error?